# Using repeating image to display the status bar / header for a screen

Tags: android

I have implement something like the following on J2me.
Is it possible to implement the same for Android?

i> I have a strip of image which I am keeping on the drawable folder. The image width & height is small.

ii> Now , using Android code & layout xml , I want to repeat displaying the small image strip so that an entire status bar / header is drawn for a screen with the use of repeating images.(mutiple image strips will ultimately draw the entire header)

The reason for implementing the header / status bar in this manner is to avoid keeping the entire header image on the drawable folder which increases the mobile application size.

Kindly provide me your inputs/sample code if anyone has done any implementation with the above logic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have tiled bitmaps in android.

If your tile is in `drawable/background.png`, then in `drawable/background_tile.xml`:

```
<bitmap android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background" 
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

And then you can set the background of a `View` to be your tiled bitmap in your layout:

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tile"/>
```

You could set the background of a `LinearLayout` or other `View` subclass as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) I would strongly recommend using a nine patch if at all possible (Especially recommend at least checking out the draw9Patch tool if you havent already) [Android draw9Patch info](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

2.) I've had issues with the tileMode xml attribute being ignored, so had to use the following code to enable the tileMode (this may have been a bug in 1.5)

```
/**
* Set up any UI elements
*/
private void setUpUI() {
    // Add tiling background
    View backgroundLayout = findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);
    BitmapDrawable bgImage = (BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wood_bg);
    bgImage.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    backgroundLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(bgImage);
}
```

Code snippet taken from [Gaunt Face - Where-To-Do Post](http://www.gauntface.co.uk/pages/blog/2009/08/20/where-to-do-android-part-2/)